# What does in-major classes mean?

Tags: computer-science, grades, gpa

I am starting to fill out my resume and I looked up a few "recommendations" on what to do. When it got to the GPA, it mentioned that you can list your cumulative, in-major, in-minor, or even last semester GPA (clearly labeled and marked as such).

I was just wondering, what "in-major" meant. Does it mean the classes directly related to my major (Computer Engineering) or does it mean my classes in upper-division or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In-major means classes related to your major. In your case, these would be all the Computer Engineering classes you have taken as well as any major requirements from outside the department. These do not include classes required by the school (e.g. writing requirements) or high level classes from outside the department that do not related to your major.

Comment: So, essentially, none of the general ed. classes are included into the In-major GPA? And thank you for your answer!

Comment: Exactly. No need to include all those pesky English and History courses they made you take. But it also means you have to leave out that Jazz 101 course you took for the easy A.